# jQuery animate += and latest version

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Each time I click the div "blue" it moves 100px. It worked well and one day I realize it stopped working. After trying a lot of things I discovered that the problem is with the latest version of jQuery 1.10 Now it just moves 100px once. It is as it ignores the += . I could not find if it is deprecated? If so, what is the right way to do that now?

You could see it working here:http://jsfiddle.net/RB4eJ/1/
(This is working in jQuery 1.9.1. But it is not in 1.10)

```
$(function(){
    $(".blue").click(function() {
        $(".blue").animate({left: "+=100"}, 500)    
    });
})
```

Comment: same issue for jq 2.x

Comment: some other also reported this http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/24/jquery-1-10-0-and-2-0-1-released/

Comment: I read changelog and there is no note about animate so it seems to be bug.

Comment: It seems this bug has already been reported on [jQuery's site](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13939)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is a bug I hope they fix it because it was useful. However for now you can do something like this:

```
$(".blue").click(function() {
    var new_left = +$(this).css("left").replace("px", "") + 100;
    $(".blue").animate({left: new_left + "px"}, 500)    
});
```

Or as @adeneo suggested:

```
$(".blue").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({left: $(this).position().left+100}, 500);  
});
```

**[See working demo with jQuery 2.x](http://jsfiddle.net/RB4eJ/3/)**

**[Performance test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-animate/2)**

Comment: Or just `$(this).animate({left: $(this).position().left+100}, 500)`

Comment: changed my mind, `offset()` would work with this example as it's relative to the document, but `position()` should really be used as that's relative to the parent in the same way CSS left would normally be with position relative or absolute.

Comment: @adeneo i think that is a common mistake. I am never sure about which one is relative to the parent or not and need to go to the documentation all the time

Comment: This is a good option. I put it here:http://jsfiddle.net/RB4eJ/3/ Thank you both!

Comment: @Nrc Note: This is a workaround. You could wait for a hot-fix soon from jQuery.

Comment: @vega I think the best option now is to use the 1.9 version. But it is good to have this workaround, just in case we need 2.0

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in animate when using `+=` or `-=`. The bug seems to at line

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L48-L50

Below is the code reference,

```
// If a +=/-= token was provided, we're doing a relative animation
tween.end = parts[ 1 ] ?
    //v--- bug
    start + ( parts[ 1 ] + 1 ) * parts[ 2 ] :  
   +parts[ 2 ];
```

changing the above should fix the bug,

```
// If a +=/-= token was provided, we're doing a relative animation
tween.end = parts[ 1 ] ?
    //v-- changed to tween.start
    tween.start + ( parts[ 1 ] + 1 ) * parts[ 2 ] :  
   +parts[ 2 ];
```

**Fix tested with fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/xEhuR/ [check line 8878]

**Note:** Well, the above doesn't accomplish much than identifying the issue.. You should stick to a workaround or wait till a fix from jQuery.

Posted in ticket http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13939?comment:10#comment:10

Comment: it would be nice if you create a new ticket in the jQuery bug tracker with your solution. It may accelerate the fix

Comment: @letiagoalves Posted in ticket http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13939?replyto=10#comment:10

Comment: @letiagoalves http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13939?comment:10#comment:11 - fixed already

Comment: nice. hope that next release is coming soon

Comment: @letiagoalves Seems like a hot-release 1.10.1 is out already http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/30/jquery-1-10-1-and-2-0-2-released/.

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed a bug in version 1.10.0 and fixed in 1.10.1

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/30/jquery-1-10-1-and-2-0-2-released/

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13939

Comment: But I try it here with version 2.0.1 and it does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/RB4eJ/4/

Comment: Did you try it with 1.10.1?